# Slide animation with navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-navigation

I'm using JetPack navigation component to navigate between fragments.
I've added slide animation between 2 fragments in graph xml:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_Fragment_to_DetailsFragment"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_left"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_right"
    app:destination="@id/DetailsFragment" />
```

The problem is - b/c I'm using navigation component and it uses `fragmentManager.replace()`, instead of `fragmentManager.add()`, instead of smooth animation I see that:

1. the first fragment disappears
2. animation of 2nd fragment is being triggered and sliding new fragment to a screen
3. 2nd fragment appears on a screen.

And b/c I have different content on both screens, it looks buggy. 
I want to implement is "like in IOS" where user sees 2 layers of screens, sliding from each other. Is there a way to implement it with Navigation component which doesn't support "`fragmentManager.add()`"?

I've also tried

```
app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
```

but situation is not much better.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Were you able to find a solution/workaround for it?

Comment: @AshrayMehta I've added the answer. That's all I have for now. If you get better answer lemme know

Comment: @AshrayMehta I found the way how to do that and posted new answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally I found the way how to do it.

1. in a graph, set the animation:

```html
<action
        android:id="@+id/action_DetailsFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_left"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/wait_anim"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/wait_anim"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_right"
        app:destination="@id/detailsFragment" />
```

2. Creatie animations:

   slide_left.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

slide_right.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

wait_anim.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300">
</translate>
```

3. To make it look better, in DetailsFragment add:

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(getView()!!, 100f)
   }
4. You can also add `sharedElementTransitions` to make your animation more unique.

Comment: Thanks so much! You saved my time! 
The "wait_anim" was exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

If anyone wants to achieve this animation in fragments with enter and exit.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/vBKZPsr.gif]

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_sign_in_to_fragmentMemberValidate"
    app:destination="@id/fragmentMemberValidate"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_slide_in_right"
    app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_slide_out_left"
    app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_slide_out_right"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_slide_in_left"/>
```

nav_slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

nav_slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

nav_slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

nav_slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I was ably to improve animation using:

- [SharedElement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html) for some parts of a screen
- adding alpha to the animation
- increasing the speed of a slide animation so the "empty space" is not that visible

But still wasn't able to implement "IOS - like" slide animation.